# GETDATE() returns NULL in an UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem is in the title, I'd like to update a field with `GETDATE()` to get the current time when the query is executed but it returns a null value. I previously saw that the column must not be `nullable` and the column default must be '`NULL`' in order to work, which is the case.

The column where I want the `GETDATE()` is `'dt_saisie'`

Here is my query :

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE [proliv_min].[dbo].[proliv_production] 
        SET 
        dt_saisie = GETDATE(), 
        dcf = null, 
        login = 'user', 
        commentaire = '[TEST] Update' 
    WHERE 
        id_kopf = ( 
            SELECT 
                id 
            FROM 
                [proliv_min].[dbo].[proliv_kopf] 
            WHERE 
                1=1 
                AND cprj = '962753' 
                AND statut IS NULL
        );
END
```

Thanks for any help

Pierre

Comment: `GETDATE()` will **never** return a *`NULL`*. The only thing I can think of is that your `UPDATE` statement isn't updating any rows as nothing meets your `WHERE` criteria. (also, what is the meaning of `1=1`? This is just a waste of the query analysis time and resources).

Comment: share the code  SELECT 
                id 
            FROM 
                [proliv_min].[dbo].[proliv_kopf] 
            WHERE 
                1=1 
                AND cprj = '962753' 
                AND statut IS NULL statement

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, your comment helped me figure what was wrong. It was one of my previous INSERT that gave me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following query to update your data. I have changed to add `in` in where condition. Because if you do not get data in `select` statement, no update will happen in your table.

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE [proliv_min].[dbo].[proliv_production] 
        SET 
        dt_saisie = GETDATE(), 
        dcf = null, 
        login = 'user', 
        commentaire = '[TEST] Update' 
    WHERE 
        id_kopf in ( 
            SELECT 
                id 
            FROM 
                [proliv_min].[dbo].[proliv_kopf] 
            WHERE 
                1=1 
                AND cprj = '962753' 
                AND statut IS NULL
        );
END
```